# passing jquery element reference to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, var

I'm trying to do something very simple with javascript but can't quite get my head around it. I'm not sure what format I should be passing the var address as.

```
$(function() {
    $('.latlng').each(function(){
        var address = $(this).html();
        getMap(address);
    });
});

function getMap(address) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(address),
        ...
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error when I pass the JQuery ref to normal javascript: *TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.position=b')*. Any help appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `getMap(address)`?

Comment: are you sure you want to get html() from .latlng and not text() ?

Comment: jQuery is a library running on top of JavaScript, not a separate language.  It doesn't do anything that JavaScript cannot.  You don't ever pass anything from jQuery to "normal" JavaScript because jQuery functions are really just JavaScript functions.

Comment: @Aaron apoligies for wrongly leaving in the old var latlng in the code example, I made a small adjustment when posting the code but forgot a small bit of it. Corrected it now

Comment: The error is most likely coming from mapDiv, unless you defined that globally and it didn't make it into your sample code.

Comment: Oh, and in general, if you want to get a DOM object from a jQuery object, you do it like this:  $("jquery selector")[0]

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly and you posted this code correctly, you pass a **non-existing object** lasting to `getMap()`, while you want to pass the address object. What happens if you correct this?

jQuery instances are just normal javascript objects like all others, so there should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the variable `latLng` to `getMap`, but its value isn't set. Your `ready` function at the top should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.latlng').each(function(){
        var address = $(this).html();
        getMap(this);
    });
});
```

Or, if you're trying to pass the `address` variable you set, make your ready function look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.latlng').each(function(){
        var address = $(this).html();
        getMap(address);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with jquery or javascript.
You are passing the wrong data into the [LatLng method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).

You need to pass in two parameters to the LatLng method:
    ...

```
var mapDiv = $('#mapDiv')[0], // also make sure the div is a regular dom node
    lat = 7.1011123,
    lng = 4.6667566;

function getMap(address) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ), // you must pass in two parameters
        ...
    });
}
```

If you are trying to get your LatLng coords from a text div then you need to convert your strings into floats.

Supposing the following html is what you use:

```
<ul>
    <li class="latlng">7.4142335,3.1296874</li>
    <li class="latlng">8.4135039,-5.1256828</li>
    <li class="latlng">-14.4101158,-5.2810335</li>
</ul>
```

Then this would be the function running `getMap()` for every `.latlng` list item:

```js
$('.latlng').each(function( i ){
    var address = $(this).text();
    address = address.split(','); // convert your text into an array

    // send in your lat and lng strings parsed as floats
    getMap(
        parseFloat( address[0] ),
        parseFloat( address[1] )
    );
});
```